# Calculate 2 timestamp in attendance

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Any ideas how to calculate attendance `datetime` in MySQL.

For example: I want to get the total hours that a person worked in a day. in given.

MySQL structures:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
id   |   datetime         |   Status    |  employeeID
-----------------------------------------------------
1    | 18-Feb-13 8:00:00  |  Check in   |    100A
2    | 18-Feb-13 10:00:00 |  Check in   |    100A
3    | 18-Feb-13 17:00:00 |  Check Out   |    100A
```

Still the total hours is 8 hours excluding the break time 12:00 pm.

Comment: Is the dataset complete?  Are you missing check out status?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP way to do the date math:

```
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y G:i:s', '18-Feb-13 8:00:00');
$datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y G:i:s', '18-Feb-13 17:00:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%h hours %i minutes %S seconds');
echo $elapsed;
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/08XWR)

You'll need to do more math to deal with breaks but this should get you started.

Reference

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you where to have a check out status when people leave, then you can do a self join.
Something like:

```
Select day(e.datetime) as day, employeeid, 
       (max(e.datetime) - min(s.datetime)) as timespend
from table1 e
inner join table1 s on (day(e.datetime) = day(s.datetime) and e.id <> s.id)
where s.status = 'check in' and e.status = 'check out'
group by day(e.datetime), employeeid
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everyone who works takes an hour off at noon, then this query should work using `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, grouping by each employee and each date:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, 
           MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'Check In' THEN DateTime END), 
           MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Check Out' THEN DateTime END))-1 as HoursWorked, 
  EmployeeId, 
  Date(DateTime)
FROM YourTable T
GROUP BY EmployeeId, Date(DateTime)
```

And here is a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e3f4/4).

Comment: @Japeth -- no problem, glad I could help :)  BTW, if an answer helped you out, please mark it as accepted to help future users of the site.  Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @sgeddes Is it possible to compute the minutes?

Comment: @Japeth -- But of course :)  Look into everything you can do with TimeStampDiff.  And here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e3f4/7